# How to get exact call time?

Tags: nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop, call-history

How can I get the exact time that a specific call took place? If I go to "recents" in the phone app, I see entries with times that read like `Mobile, Yesterday`. I need the exact time, down to the minute.

Comment: If you click on the specific call in the call log, it should take you to a screen that shows the exact time.  What kind of phone do you have?  OS?  A few extra details would help out tremendously

Comment: Nexus 5, Android 5.0.1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For Android 5.0.x Lollipop:

1. Either on "Recents" or "Call History", tap the entry you want to see. It will open a mini-menu under the entry with options "Call back" and "Details".
2. Select "Details" to see the call details.
3. From here, you can see the time when you receive/miss a call, and also the duration of the call.

[image: Call Details on Phone app]

<sub>Click the image for larger variant</sub>

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [Andrew's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/95991/44325), you need to click the entry and *not the picture of the contact* for the mini-menu to appear.  I was clicking the picture of the contact, and it pulls up the contact info - not the call detail.